# Rank() function with WHERE clause display nothing MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have to find student max scores from each of their organization, I comes up with the solution by applying RANK() function:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

INSERT INTO interviewqs.details(scores,name,organization)
    VALUES
    (30,"Daniel","OWARD UNI"),
    (40,"Kayla","OWARD UNI"),
    (12,"Hope","ZELENSKY UNI"),
    (50,"Osman","ZELENSKY UNI"),
    (4,"Daniel","REWARD UNI"),
    (77,"Joe","REWARD UNI");
DESCRIBE interviewqs.details;

# Find the student with highest scores from each organization
    
SELECT DISTINCT organization,name,scores,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY organization ORDER BY scores DESC)
        AS "rank"
        FROM details
        WHERE "rank" = 1;
```

The problem is when I executed the code the output display empty table,

Without 'WHERE' function applied

```
organization name scores rank 
OWARD UNI   Kayla   40  1
OWARD UNI   Daniel  30  3
REWARD UNI  Daniel  77  1
REWARD UNI  Daniel  30  2
REWARD UNI  Daniel  4   4
ZELENSKY UNI Osman  50  1
ZELENSKY UNI Hope   12  3
```

With 'WHERE' function applied

```
organization name scores rank
```

What mistake did I do here?

Comment: Try enclosing the two `rank` in backtics like this `\`rank\`` instead of this `"rank"`, because the `"rank"` in your `WHERE` clause is treated as a *string* and not as a *column*.

Comment: @Kuro Neko "Unknown column name 'rank' in 'where clause'", displays after I used your method, why?

Comment: You cannot use output expression which applies window function in WHERE and even in HAVING. Move your query into CTE and apply your WHERE in outer query.

Comment: *Without 'WHERE' function applied* Impossible output for shown source data and shown query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use window functions in `WHERE` clause. The reason is that `WHERE` clause are processed first before window functions. I would highly suggest you to read up an article, [Why Can't I use RANK() in Where Clause](https://learnsql.com/blog/window-functions-not-allowed-in-where/#:%7E:text=You%20can%27t%20use%20window,FROM%2C%20JOIN)

To solve this, change your query to using CTE or subquery as shown below:

Subquery:

```
SELECT organization, name, scores
FROM (
    SELECT 
        organization, name, scores,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY organization ORDER BY scores DESC) AS rnk
    FROM details
) tmp
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, What's the point of 'tmp' presence?

Comment: @STACKOVERFLOWUSER This is subquery alias (temporary name). Each table (even subquery) must have a name - without it you cannot refer to its columns while ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       organization,
       FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (PARTITION BY organization ORDER BY scores DESC) name,
       MAX(scores) OVER (PARTITION BY organization) scores
FROM details
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way using CTE.

```
WITH tmp AS 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT organization, `name`, scores,
  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY organization ORDER BY scores DESC) `rank`
  FROM details
)
SELECT organization, `name`, scores FROM tmp WHERE `rank` = 1;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2FNUfcg1fqg1kmKNx77L2t/1)

Note : `rank` is a reserve word so you must be careful in using it, always embed it in backticks.

Check [MySQL Common Table Expression](https://www.javatpoint.com/mysql-common-table-expression) for more details about CTE.

> In MySQL, every statement or query produces a temporary result or relation. A common table expression or CTE is used to name those temporary results set that exist within the execution scope of that particular statement

Comment: `rank` column is not used in the output, so it is more safe to use another name and not quoting.